# Lua Tables // Loop // Wow Addons // Index as a Variable

Tags: loops, lua, add-on

I found it very inefficient for the game function to get a specific value. I wanted to try to get all the values from the function once, put it to the table, and then access it by indexes instead of loops multiple times

```
for j=1,10 do
a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10 = GetAuraWithIndex(j)
at["player"]={[a10]={a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10}}
end
```

lets me access the table this way:

```
at["player"][783][10]
```

Still I am not able to insert multiple results to the table with what I ve got.
It only created index with the values that represent the last a10 in the "j" loop

```
for j=1,10 do
```

Is it possible to make it work the way I want so I get table with all the results instead only the last one in the loop? I am able to print a10 during the loop and it prints the designed for me values of a10 (I mean it I am pretty sure I didn't make any mistake elsewhere in the code)

This is what my code inserts into the table.

```
at={
    player={
            [783]={
                   [1]="important data"
                   [2]="important data"
                   [3]="important data"
                   [4]="important data"
                   [5]="important data"
                   [6]="important data"
                   [7]="important data"
                   [8]="important data"
                   [9]="important data"
                   [10]=783
                  }
            }
}
```

So instead inserting data for for all the loop, it inserts only for j=10.

Comment: you just need to do `[a10]={....` the `[` around the value make the table constructor take the variable value rather than the identifier as the intended key value

Comment: your example table doesn't make sense. `at={["player"]={132123={123,321,123,231,213,213,123,213,213,231}}`   what is `a10`? `132123` or `231` ? It can't be both at the same time

Comment: @Piglet Hi, yeah thats mistake on my side when I wanted to show example of a table. It is supposed to be the same value,( I edited it) a10 is a number, all others are strings/numbers/booleans

Answer (score 1):

```
for j=1,aura_count do
local a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10 = GetAuraWithIndex(j)
at[unit]={[a10]={a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10}}
end
```

Inside this loop `unit` does not change. Hence you'll overwrite `at[unit]` for every `j` from `1` to `aura_count`.

I don't know how you want to organize your data but you could simply do something like this:

```
at[unit].data = {}
for j=1,aura_count do
  local a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10 = GetAuraWithIndex(j)
  at[unit].data[j]={[a10]={a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10}}
end
```

Comment: Hi, I wasn't able to post the whole code, but the rest of my code loops the [unit] and surprisingly it works and inserts my [unit] as intended. The problem is that my [a10] inserts only one value and this value is equal to the last value in the loop so exactly to a10 = GetAuraWithIndex(aura_count)

Comment: at[unit].data[j]={[a10]={a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10}} This is what i want to avoid, I acces my table with UnitID and SpellID which is equal a10. If I write to the table data[j], I will need to loop through the table to find it. Accessing with [a10] would be more efficient

Comment: then use a10 instead of j? I don't know your code I can only guess. you complained about having only having the last entry. so I showed you how to store more than 1 entry

Comment: Thank you so much, I was hoping myself to make it look more cleaner. Seems like this is the only way to implement it in lua. Besides I have to make a table at[unit]={} followed by at[unit].data={} it works as intended, i had hopes that it could look more cleaner and i was able to avoid that messy code. Gonna check how it performs. Thank you so much again!